# AASM Adding callbacks in a child class

Tags: ruby, aasm

Is there a way to add callbacks in a child model when AASM is defined in a parent model?

```
class Parent
  include AASM
  aasm do
    state :initialised, :initial => true
    state :filled_out
    state :authorised

    event :fill_out do
      transitions :from => :initialised, :to => :filled_out
    end

    event :authorise, :before => :stamp_it do
      transitions :from => :filled_out, :to => :authorised
    end

    def stamp_it
      puts "Stamped"
    end
  end
end
```

In the child class we want to add the callback `mail_it`. It appears we have to redefine the entire `event` from the parent to add another callback?

```
class Child < Parent
  aasm do
    event :authorise, :before => [:stamp_it, :mail_it] do
      transitions :from => :filled_out, :to => :authorised
    end
  end

  def mail_it
    puts "Mail it"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update event in your Child class

```
class Child

  def initialize
    event = self.class.aasm.events.select{|e| e.name == :authorise}[0]
    event.options[:before] = [:stamp_it, :mail_it]
  end

end
```